# Javamail multiple recepints with multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, email, jakarta-mail

I have to send an email to several recipients. I don't want the header to display the complete list of recipients(i.e. I am not using "Message.RecipientType.CC"). If I use "Message.RecipientType.BCC", there is a probability of the mail being sent to spam. So I am using Message.RecipientType.TO to send an email one at a time. The problem is that this can take a very long time. My question is whether a separate thread can be created for every email to be sent in order to improve performance.

Comment: What is your "big picture" description of your eMail need (in what context). Does your Java application only do eMail, or more things? (There are some other options for you if you have eMail requirement only)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I will be sending a newsletter of sorts to many recipients.

Comment: You may be better off using a commercial service like MailChimp (free for 12000 emails per month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate thread for each message, which will require a separate connection to the mail server.  Depending on your mail server, it may limit the number of connections you can use.

You can also send the messages serially, using a single connection.  Again, depending on your mail server, it may limit the number of messages you can send in a single connection.

Comment: If you are sending many eMail message there are quite a few things you will have to do to ensure that mail you send does not get marked as spam .. and to ensure that you don't exceed the emails per day of your service.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII: Thank you for the heads-up. I already know how to prevent my messages from being perceived as spam(to a certain degree of course) and know that there is a limit to emails that can be sent per day. Regarding to your advice on using MailChimp, is there a way to integrate sending mail with javamail with MailChimp?

Comment: @Bill Shannon: I want to share a Session object with multiple threads and use Transport.send(mgs) in each. Will this work? I want to use several threads to improve performance as sending a message one by one is too slow. And also how does the Transport.send call determine the host and other settings? Does it derive them frome the message object somehow?

Comment: Yes, it will work.  Each call to Transport.send will create a new connection to your mail server.  The mail server configuration comes from the Session properties.  If all messages are going to the same mail server (the usual case), it's going to be better to send more than one message per connection.

Comment: @NwaiwuGilbert while there is no javamail to Mailchimp integration, Mailchimp does have a rich API (JSON based) that can be used to create campaigns and send eMail.